# Security: Oauth and Mobile apps

Tags: mobile, ios, oauth

This is what I believe are the security implications of integrating Oauth using embedded webview vs browser in mobile application.

```
Embedded Webview
* Keep UI for mobile app

 Security implications 
    * Makes phishing easy (especially since no address bar to show url and security)

Browser
* Different UI/Context switch (downsides)

Security - (good) :Less phishing ... can see url in address bar
(bad): Bad app can take over custom url scheme and have access to code.
```

Is there a way to have a secure mobile solution for oauth integration in mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser + PIN-code verification (`oauth_callback=oob`). It will become semi-automatic, but will allow you to avoid creating "custom url scheme"

see [this article](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization), for example